# Live Database Sync. MySQL - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, mysql, replication, data-synchronization

I have a rare scenario. Is there any possibility to achieve the target? Here is the situation:

I have developed a responsive site for a supermarket. I am using php with foundation framework and the back-end is MySQL. It is for promoting their products. They already having software for billing, which was developed using WPF with SQL Server back-end. Now they need to include online shopping in the web site, and they need to reduce the product from the local software according to the online sale.

I can use [replication](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/870358/Bidirectional-Replication-in-MySQL) if both the databases are the same. But in this case, the local DB is SQL Server and the live DB is MySQL. How can I achieve the target of syncing live and local DBs?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linked Server for SQL Server side. Creata a stored procedure to check online mysql tables data. If product sold decrease the local product count on the Local SQL Server.

Why do you cover this problem on the application side using transaction ?